# push notifications does not received when app is closed in "vivo" and "xiaomi" devices

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase, firebase-notifications

how can I receive the firebase push notification, when app is closed on "vivo" and "xiaomi" devices?
"vivo" and "xiaomi" devices are not getting the **Notification message** when app is closed so I tried with the **Data-only message with high priority flag**, but it also not works.

**Code which I used to send the Data-only message:**

```
"to": "",
"priority":"high",
"data": {
   title: "test",
},
}
```

Comment: On Xiaomi devices, there is permission "start in the background" in context of you application and it must be turned on. It doesn't guarantee to resolve your problem, but you could try.

Answer (score 0):

most of the Xiaomi phones has this option "Don't keep activities" as default in the developer option, which kills the app once it's in the background, making it unable to receive any notifications. Disable that option and it works fine.
Also here is the complete format for data notificaiton

```
{
 "message":{
"token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
"data":{
  "Nick" : "Mario",
  "body" : "great match!",
  "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
}
 }
  }
```